# bin subdirectories have no generated packages directories

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I am using Dart 1.3.6 SDK and generated a typical command line application with a bin directory. The bin directory automatically gets its packages directory. However, none of the subdirectories of the bin directory gets any packages directory. As such I cannot import packages such as http that I am trying to use.

According to Dart's literature I think bin, test, web and example directories should all generate packages in there sub-directories. Yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the info that `pub get` should create these directories. I just created the symlinks manually when they were missing.

https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16947

Comment: Thanks Gunter. It seems that even resetting the entry points does not create the symlinks after running pub get either.

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't for me either, I guess this is why I stick with manual creation. I'll add a comment to the issue, maybe someone responds.

Comment: I tried to just copy the packages directory to a subdirectory of bin but the package are still not resolved. How do you add your symlinks manually.

Comment: I don't know for windows. In Linux `ln -s ../../../packages packages` (../../.. up to the directory that contains the `pubspec.yaml` file.

Answer (score 0):

So far "entry points" in sub directories are not supported:

See also:

- https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18589
- https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17596